# Java How to redraw JPanel (re-create object)?

Tags: java, swing, resize, drawing, jpanel

I have a problem that, I need to only redraw/rebuild the drawing area if the "c" key is pressed.
The way I'm doing using repaint(), turns out to be causing the draw area to be of position.
I also notice that, whenever I re-size the frame, the keylistener is no longer working.

Problems:

1. unable to repaint correctly.
2. keylistener is not working after frame is re-sized.

Love to attach the display, but seems like it is blocked because I am newbie.

The following code is the main function that call the class "newZone".

```
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() { 

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e){
            System.out.println("component Rebuild"); 
            frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
            frame.getContentPane().invalidate();
            JComponent newContentPane = new newZone(frame.getSize());
            newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
            frame.getContentPane().add(newContentPane);
            frame.getContentPane().revalidate();
            frame.setContentPane(newContentPane); 
        }
    });
```

The following is the class of newZone, which contains Paint & keylistener:

```
public class newZone extends JComponent implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {

JPanel panel1;
JTextArea textArea;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
MyDrawingTool Drawing;
static int firsttimer = 0;
static int preposX = 0;
static int preposY = 0;
static int widthPercentage = 80 , heightPercentage = 93;
static int numberOfYboxes,numberOfXboxes;
static Dimension currentPanelSize;
static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();


public newZone(Dimension currentPanelSize1) {

    currentPanelSize = currentPanelSize1; 

    Drawing = new MyDrawingTool();
    Drawing.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Drawing.setBounds(  10, 10, 
                        (int) currentPanelSize.getWidth()*(widthPercentage)/100, 
                        (int) currentPanelSize.getHeight()*(heightPercentage)/100 );
    Drawing.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( (int) currentPanelSize.getWidth()*(widthPercentage)/100,
                                            (int) currentPanelSize.getHeight()*(heightPercentage)/100));

    Drawing.addMouseListener(this);
    Drawing.addMouseMotionListener(this);

    add(Drawing);

    addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
    {
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){ 
             System.out.println( "Key type: "+e.getKeyChar()); 

             if(e.getKeyChar() == 'c'){
                 Drawing.redraw();
             }
         }
    });
    setFocusable(true);
}


class MyDrawingTool extends JPanel{

    void redraw(){

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics q){

        //super.paint(q);

        int j,k, width, height;
        int startX = 10, startY = 10;
        int boxSize = 50;

        width  = (int)currentPanelSize.getWidth()*(widthPercentage)/100;
        height = (int)currentPanelSize.getHeight()*(heightPercentage)/100;

        numberOfYboxes = (height-20)/50;
        numberOfXboxes = (width-20)/50;

        for ( j = 0; j < numberOfYboxes; j++)
        {   
            startX  = 10;
            for ( k = 0; k < numberOfXboxes; k++)
            {   
                q.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                q.fillRect(startX, startY, boxSize, boxSize);
                q.setColor(Color.BLUE); //Set line color
                q.drawRect(startX, startY, boxSize, boxSize);
                startX+=boxSize;
            }
            startY+=boxSize;

        } 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are using a ComponentListener. I don't see any reason to remove/add/invalidate/revalidat and do all the other stuff.

All you need to do is add the panel to the CENTER of a content pane of the frame. The panel will automatically increase/decrease in size as the frame resizes. There is no need for the ComponentListener.

Custom painting should be done in the paintComponent() method and don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(...) at the start.

The KeyListener doesn't work because focus is now on the JFrame (not the panel) after you resize the frame. You should NOT be using a KeyListener for this. Instead you should be [Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which work even when the panel doesn't have focus.

Comment: camickr thanks..yeah seem like the paintComponent work perfectly~! The reason i am using the absolute position I feel like in more control compares to center.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you do not need to switch content pane at all. 
If you use some layout on default content pane, as @camickr suggested, you won't need to handle resize and other stuff manually.
Good luck there.